# How do I color my output in the console in Intellij using Grep Console?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

This is my first question to StackOverflow:

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA on a Mac. Intellij does not support ANSI coloring of the output (I want to use it for coloring a ludoboard, that i'm representing in the console). So i'm trying to get Grep Console to work - but i don't know how. The only guides I could find, using google, refer to Eclipse or are not specific, so i'm out of IDEAs.

Can anyone please ELI5?

Comment: Grep console is for testing regular expressions, so I don't think it's going to help you much. You should exercise your app on the mac terminal, which should support ansi colours.

Comment: No, it is not. Regexp tester plugin is for testing of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, in the settings of Grep Console, just check "Enable ANSI coloring" and in the next run, it will be colored. If not then there is some issue with the console and you should create an issue either on github for the plugin, or on jetbrains issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked like a charm. I am now representing each players tokens by coloring the background on the token:
public final String NORMAL = "\u001B[0m";
public final String GREEN_B = "\u001B[42m";
public final String RED_B = "\u001B[41m";
public final String BLUE_B = "\u001B[44m";
public final String YELLOW_B = "\u001B[43m";
public final String[] PLAYERCOLORS = {GREEN_B, BLUE_B, YELLOW_B, RED_B};
PLAYERCOLORS[currentPlayer.playerID-1] + "T" + NORMAL

Comment: This answer no longer applies. Grep Console settings do not have an "Enable ANSI coloring" option, starting in version 6.4 (feb 2017, IJ 2016+).   :(

Comment: @CMerrill The question no longer applies either, it is supported by IntelliJ. If it is not working, then report a bug. No plugin can solve it anymore.

Comment: @Meo How is ANSI coloring this supported natively in  IntelliJ?