# How can I use ANSI color output in the IntellIJ console (2019.3)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jansi

I'm using a very nice Java text coloring library [jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) which works perfectly when I run the my code from a DOS prompt or a LINUX terminal.

Unfortunately most of the time I find myself running code from my IntellIJ IDE (2019.3) and the console doesn't respect the ANSI coloring. Is there anyway round this? I did come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565824/how-do-i-color-my-output-in-the-console-in-intellij-using-grep-console) which discusses using the grep console plugin for this purpose, but this no longer works.

Is there any plugin or configuration settings that will allow me to use ANSI coloring and commands in the IntellIJ console?

Comment: It is [already natively supported](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207125285-Intellij-14-console-not-respecting-ANSI-colors). Just tested in my IDE https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEeFM.png

Comment: Well this statement 
System.out.println("\u001B[31m" + "This text has red text but a default background!" + "\u001B[0m");
doesn't color in my console...

Comment: Which run configuration type are you using to run your code?

Comment: Does https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006477540-Is-there-any-way-that-i-can-change-the-color-of-the-text-output-in-the-console-in-the-program- help?

Comment: No doesn't work for me - could be the the version of IntellIJ, my settings other plugins, possibly the color theme, other conflicting libraries - I guess it's a matter of a process of elimination.  Good to know it's possible at least in theory....

Answer (score 1):

From Intellij terminal you can simply run `mvn install -Dstyle.color=always -Djansi.force=true`

If you run Intellij's maven using command in Maven-panel, or execute it in your Run -> Edit Configurations

[image]

Then configure Intellij Maven settings like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/WTiHJF4.png]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me when console output was going to System.out or System.err using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)

Comment: This is a logger setup, it doesn't cover non-logger console output.

Comment: I am talking about logger output being sent from a running java program in intelij.

Comment: System.out is not a logger output. This is a console output. No logger is involved here. Try using Logback, and embedded one from SpringBoot, for example. Or simply add Lombok @Slf4j class annotation and log.info() method.